# Track user attendance to specific events

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

Im trying to track user attendance to a specified events, I have the longitude and the latitude of each event in Json file and each event has starting time and Ending time, when the user attends one of the specified events, this event will be added to VC that include all the tracked, attended events. The way I want to do it, is if the device tracked that the user current location is the same location as one of the events in the list and **if the user has been to this event location more than one hour** then mark this event as attended and add it to the AttendedVC. I already know how to do the first part of this (the user current location is the same location as one of the events), but I have no idea how to do the timing part or even if it possible to do it in Xcode. I would really appreciate any examples or tutorials about this topic.

Comment: Please explore `NSTimer`

Comment: And also look at NSDate.

Comment: @AbhishekBedi could u plzz clarify more, becuz according to what I read on NSTimer, it is used if i want to suspend the tracking for a period of time (seconds), how could that possibly help me ??

Comment: @matt could u plzz clarify more ??

Answer (score 0):

> if the user has been to this event location more than one hour then mark this event as attended and add it to the AttendedVC

1. With time component of `NSDate` you can get the time of the event. To know how much time the user has spent at a location, you should initialize an `NSTimer` of 1 hour immediately you receive the user's location.
2. When the timer expires, you know that the user has been to that location.

Please clarify incase this is not what you expect.

Comment: the event starting time is a fixed key in Json file, where each different event starts at a different time. I didn't get u when u said get the time of the event by NSDate since each time of the event going to be already saved in json file !!! can u illustrate more what u said by an example code so that i get what u mean or if u could link me to any tutorials that shows that, would be very helpful for me.